# How to direct fire effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, effects

I am trying to create a sort of "fighting" type scene where balls of fire are around our hands. I want to get that visual effect where it is also trailing slightly behind the movement of the hands so that it looks like it's swinging through the air.

The problem is, the fire is just sort of globing up around my hand. It's also showing over top of my arm, which realistically, it should pass behind it and out of sight.

How can I secure these two effects to get a more realistic looking fire from my blend?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Posting images/screenshots will be very helpful. Many people will answer if there are images, but not if it means downloading your file, opening it up, figuring out how you did what you did, figuring out how to do what you want... etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can use masking for that, add a mask in the motion tracking editor.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and expand a little on how to achieve this. Possibly add some screenshots of the workflow.